# Prolog check if the list is like 1,2,3,4,2,1

Tags: prolog

I need to create a program to check if a list increases then decreases, just like in the example below:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,4,3,2,1]
```

and it must be at least a one step increase or decrease.

Basically:

- there must be a single ascending sequence followed by a single descending sequence.
- the step in each transition must be at least one (no identical numbers side by side).
- the step can be *more* than one.

I thought about finding the biggest number in the list and then splitting the list into two lists, then checking if they are both sorted. How can it be done easier?

Comment: Are you missing a "3" in the title and a "5" in your example?  Another question: The sequence has to start and end with the same number?

Comment: @user1118501, tried to clarify the rules based on my understanding, please let us know if they're wrong.

Comment: there is no mistake!what i need is  a predicate to check if a list initially increases and after a point reduces. We don't need the numbers be in order

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it easier:

```
up_and_down([A, B, C|Rest]) :- 
  A < B, up_and_down([B, C|Rest]).
up_and_down([A, B, C|Rest]) :-
  A < B, B > C, goes_down([C|Rest]).
goes_down([]).
goes_down([X]).
goes_down([A, B|Rest]]) :-
  A > B, goes_down([B | Rest]).
```

The first predicate checks whether the sequence is going up. When we get to the inflexion point, the second one is true. After that, we just have to check that it goes down until the end (last three).

Answer (score 1):

If all numbers used are integers, consider using [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)!

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

Based on `chain/2`, we can define `up_down_zs/3` like this:

```
up_down_zs(Up, [P|Down], Zs) :-
   Up = [_,_|_],
   Down = [_|_],
   append(Up, Down, Zs),
   append(_, [P], Up),
   chain(Up, #<),
   chain([P|Down], #>).
```

First, some cases we *all* expect to fail:

```
?- member(Zs, [[1,1],[1,2,2,1],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5,5,6,4,3,2,1]]),
   up_down_zs(_, _, Zs).
false.
```

Now, let's run some *satisfiable* queries!

```
?- up_down_zs(Up, Down, [1,2,3,4,5,6,4,3,2,1]).
(  Up = [1,2,3,4,5,6], Down = [6,4,3,2,1] 
;  false
).

?- up_down_zs(Up, Down, [1,2,3,1]).
(  Up = [1,2,3], Down = [3,1]
;  false
).

?- up_down_zs(Up, Down, [1,2,1]).
(  Up = [1,2], Down = [2,1]
;  false
).
```

Comment: You you elaborate on `up_down_zs(Up,Down,[1,1])`?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively :

```
pyramid(L) :-
    append(Increase, Decrease, L),
    (   append(_, [Last], Increase), Decrease = [First|_]
     -> Last > First
     ;  true),       
    forall(append([_, [A, B], _], Increase), A < B),
    forall(append([_, [C, D], _], Decrease), C > D),
    !.
```

That requires your implementation to have an `append/2` predicate defined, which is the case if you use swi for example. An adaptation to use `append/3` isn't hard to code though.