# Any additional information about Prolog's lists?

Tags: prolog

I need more information about how lists work in Prolog. 
From my what I've found it seems lists in Prolog can be divided into two parts: `[Head|Tail]`, where the `Head` is for the 1st item of the list while the `Tail` takes in the items remaining in the list. Can anyone please explain to me in more detail how this code works:

```
up_and_down([A, B, C|Rest]) :- 
   A < B,
   up_and_down([B, C|Rest]).
up_and_down([A, B, C|Rest]) :-
   A < B,
   B > C,
   goes_down([C|Rest]).

goes_down([]).
goes_down([X]).
goes_down([A, B|Rest]]) :-
   A > B,
   goes_down([B | Rest]).
```

This is a code from: [Prolog check if the list is like 1,2,3,4,2,1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650789/prolog-check-if-the-list-is-like-1-2-3-4-2-1])

I would like to make this as a basis into making a program in prolog which would identify if the list is bouncy or not, which should be something like this:

```
is_it_bouncy([1,2,3]).
false.
is_it_bouncy([3,2,1]).
false.
is_it_bouncy([1,3,2]).
True.
```

Explanations are much appreciated :D  
Edit: almost done but not sure about my if then statement. it should be like *if not ascending and descending then bouncy*  
 `bouncy([X|[Y|Zs]]):- not ascending([Y|Zs]), descending ([Y|Zs]); bouncy([Y|Zs]).`

Answer (score 0):

[A, B, C|D] is the same has writing [A|[B|C|D]], it meens that you take the three first element in your list. It work for has many element has you want as long as you're not trying to get more element than the list contain.
Si up_and_down take the first three element's of the list and check if they go up (A < B) and then down (B > C). Goes_down just check that, given the first two element's of the list A and B, A is superior to B.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! But I still don't understand some parts of it, like up_and_down([B, C|Rest]). (3rd line)
goes_down([C|Rest]). (7th line)

Comment: `[A, B, C|D]` is **not the same** was `[A|[B|C|D]]`. But it's the same as `[A|[B|[C|D]]]`.